# How to collect coefficients of the same powers?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

I am using the Symbolic Math Toolbox, and define polynomials as symbolic objects, e.g.:

```
syms a x y;
P = x^2*y + a*x*y^2 + x*y^2;
```

I am looking for a function that collects coefficients of the same powers – something like

```
collect_coeff(P,x*y^2)
```

that will return

```
a + 1
```

Would anyone have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MuPAD's `coeff` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/coeff.html)) to accomplish this [within Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/calling-mupad-functions-from-matlab.html):

```
syms a x y;
P = x^2*y + a*x*y^2 + x*y^2;
feval(symengine,'coeff',P,'[x,y]','[1,2]')
% or equivalently:
%evalin(symengine,'coeff(P,[x,y],[1,2])')
```

which returns `a + 1`. I recommend reading the full documentation for `coeff` and related MuPAD functions for manipulating [symbolic polynomials](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/roots-of-polynomials.html).